# Change categorical variable value to a word

Tags: r, variables

I have a dataframe, and in one variable that data is recorded as either 1 or 0. I would like to convert this to `Male` or `Female`.

How can this be done?

Comment: `ifelse(df$col == 1,"Male","Female")`

Comment: @user1778351 Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use either numeric index to replace the values

```
df1$Col1 <- c("Female", "Male")[(df1$Col1+1)]
df1
#    Col1
#1 Female
#2   Male
#3   Male
#4 Female
```

Or using a `key/value` vector

```
as.vector(setNames(c("Female", "Male"), c(0, 1))[as.character(df1$Col1)])
#[1] "Female" "Male"   "Male"   "Female"
```

---

Or with `ifelse` that makes it easier to understand the logic

```
df1$Col1, with(df1, ifelse(Col1==1, "Male", "Female"))
```

#### Update

If it is already a `factor` column

```
levels(df2$Col1) <- c("Female", "Male")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0))
df2 <- data.frame(Col1 = factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0)))
```

Comment: actually I was wondering, the question title states "Change categorical variable into..." which probably implies that the op's data.frame is initially a factor {0, 1}, and your first suggestion won't probably work on it.

Comment: @agenis It is not clear without an example from the OP.  But, I had seen people asking question s stating `data.table` or `matrix` for a data.frame and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

Using factor:

```
x <- c(0,1,1,0)
factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Female", "Male"))

# [1] Female Male   Male   Female
# Levels: Female Male
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best answer in your specific case, but the `recode` function from `car` package also works and it is particularly useful in case of more complex recoding rules. Also, i think it is the best way to guarantee that people reading your line of code will understand what it actually does:

```
df = data.frame('sex.num' = round(runif(5), 0))
df['sex.char'] = car::recode(df$sex.num, "0='Female'; 1='Male'")
print(df)
#### sex.num sex.char
#### 1       0   Female
#### 2       0   Female
#### 3       1     Male
#### 4       0   Female
#### 5       0   Female
```